# Joining two querysets in Django based on common field

Tags: django, orm, django-queryset

I have two querysets:

**queryset 1:**

```
[
   {'field_a': 12, 'field_b': 23}, 
   {'field_a': 24, 'field_b': 35},
]
```

**queryset 2:**

```
[
   {'field_a': 12, 'field_c': 32}, 
   {'field_a': 24, 'field_c': 43},
]
```

My goal is to get the `left join` of these two querysets based on the common field (that is, `field_a`) so that the result looks like this:

```
 [
       {'field_a': 12, 'field_b': 23, 'field_c': 32}, 
 ]
```

A little bit background on why I need this. 
I have a chat application where I am displaying the list of dialogs. For each dialog, I want the user to see the latest message and the number of unread messages.

Here are the models.

```
class Dialog(models.Model):
    pass

class Message(models.Model):
    dialog = models.ForeignKey(Dialog, ...) 
    text = models.TextField()
    is_read = models.BooleanField(default = False)
```

The problem is that I can't come up with a single query of type `Message.objects.select_related('dialog').annotate(...)` which would fetch both  the number of unread messages and the latest message.

I use the following code to fetch the last message in each dialog:

```
max_id_qs = Message.objects.values('dialog__id').\
                        annotate(max_id = Max('id'),).values('max_id')

qs = Message.objects.filter(id__in = max_id_qs).values('text')
```

And I have no idea how to fetch the number of unread messages in the same queryset. From SQL point point view, it must be some sort of sub-query, but I can't figure out what's the right syntax for sub-querying as well. Maybe the question is too broad, but I am still lost in this stuff. Please bear with me!

Comment: Can you please post the code you are using to generate these two querysets?

Comment: See the updated question